# MATLAB Decimal to ASCII

Tags: matlab, binary, ascii

I am trying to convert a 3x8 matrix to an ASCII equivalent and save it to a text file.

Each row represents a 8-bit binary number.  The steps I follow is to create a decimal value for each row, then I use `char()` to convert the decimal to ASCII.

This works OK for alphanumeric inputs.  But for an input containing the first three ASCII characters (NUL, SOH and STX), the resultant file is empty.

The code is:

```
bin_3x8 = reshape(serial,8,[]).'
dec = bin2dec(num2str(bin_3x8))
text = [char(dec).']

fileSave = fopen(filename,'w');
fprintf(fileSave,text);
fclose(fileSave);
```

Output:

```
bin_3x8 = 
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0


dec =

 0
 1
 2 

text =
```

The MATLAB console shows the text conversion is empty, I think this might be because it can not print these characters. But If I write the data to a file, the file is empty as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have given an example of your output but where is your input?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `native2unicode`. Set encoding to ascii.